# What qt components do i need for creating applications for windows 10/8 x64?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

I'm learning c++ and want to start learning qt.

I have installed the qt creator, but when I want to create a new project, it shows me an error saying " no valid kits found".

I searched the internet and finally figured out that I should install some components first.

Now I'm in "D:\qt\MaintenanceTool -> Add or remove components" and here is a huge list of components that I can install, at first I wanted to install all of them but It's like 50GB and I'm pretty sure that I don't need to install them all at this point, I'm just trying to start to learn qt.

Which Component do I need to install? I want to create desktop applications that can be run on win 10/8 or maybe 7 on 64 bit (Windows 10 is the most important one)

[image: Component selection]

Is there anything else that I should do beside installing components to get rid of "no valid kits found"? 
I compile my c++ codes with MinGW and I write codes using CLion ide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit" package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the Qt pre-compiled binaries.

So one of the MSVC components there (if you use visual studio) or one of the MinGW (select this one if you are not sure).

Note: If you select MinGW, you need to make sure that the version (32-bit or 64-bit) matches the same MinGW that you have. If you are using the one that comes with Qt, you can check it in Developer and Designer Tools:

[image]

That's all you need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting `MinGW 7.3.0` will be enought. Just choose proper 32/64 bit version - the same as in case of your mingw installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the following:

1. If you don't have any compiler then select it in *Developer and Designer Tools*. Also you can select *Debugging Tools for Windows*.
2. Then select appropriate pre-compiled binaries of Qt for selected compiler.

That's enough.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about developer and designer, I didn't know what they are.
sorry I don't have rep to upvote your answer